# woocommerce add category nav to product-category pages or dynamic pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the product categories navbar on top of the shop page. If I click on any of the category navbar, then it take me to the product-categories page, however, on top of this page, the categories navbar are unavailable. I need to embed this product category navbar to the product-categories pages too. I'm unable to add shortcodes [product_categories] because, the product-categories page is dynamic i.e. based on the filters. I've played with customize>woocommerce>shop page display & category display but nothing worked. Any assistance on this is much appreciated. Attached screen shot reference.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WooCommerce hooks.
for example

```
function filter_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $array ) { 
    



  $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
  $orderby      = 'name';  
  $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
  $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
  $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no  
  $title        = '';  
  $empty        = 0;

  $args = array(
         'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
         'orderby'      => $orderby,
         'show_count'   => $show_count,
         'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
         'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
         'title_li'     => $title,
         'hide_empty'   => $empty
  );
 $all_categories = get_categories( $args );
 foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
    if($cat->category_parent == 0) {
        $category_id = $cat->term_id;       
        echo '<br /><a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $cat->name .'</a>';

        $args2 = array(
                'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                'child_of'     => 0,
                'parent'       => $category_id,
                'orderby'      => $orderby,
                'show_count'   => $show_count,
                'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                'title_li'     => $title,
                'hide_empty'   => $empty
        );
        $sub_cats = get_categories( $args2 );
        if($sub_cats) {
            foreach($sub_cats as $sub_category) {
                echo  $sub_category->name ;
            }   
        }
    }       
}

    
    return $array; 
}; 
         
// add the filter 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'filter_woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: wow morteza ! that pretty much worked nice. How do i insert this to a particular div ?. Like a target div. thanks for the help @morteza

Comment: Hello, please.
Glad it was practical.
You can edit this section to add a div tag.

for example

echo '<div class="test"><a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $cat->name .'</a></div>';